# How do I get Perl::Critic to work with E.P.I.C and eclipse?

Tags: perl, eclipse, perl-critic, epic

I'm running eclipse Galileo with EPIC 0.5.46 and ActiveState ActivePerl 5.10.0, on WinXP SP3.

I just downloaded [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl::Critic) using the package manager, and integrated it to eclipse using the appropriate Properties page.

I can run Perl::Critic just fine from my eclipse source context menu; it runs.    But it doesn't put any markers in my source code in eclipse... in other words, I can't see its results.  (My Perl ain't that good.)

Please, if you tell me to RTFM, please point out which FM to R. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this section](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic/bin/perlcritic#EPIC) in the Perl::Critic man page. Until I discovered this note, I lived happily in the delusion that my code was good enough to pass Perl::Critic. And then I installed [criticism](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?criticism) only to discover the truth :)

You need to add the line `use criticism 'gentle';` at the top of your code. Change `gentle` to `brutal` if that suits you. Running the script or module inside EPIC then shows `Perl::Critic`'s comments in the console below the code pane.

My EPIC version is 0.6.35 BTW. I use Linux. See last section in this [thread](http://www.epic-ide.org/tracker/perl-critic-problems.php) for a possible solution with Windows

Comment: I saw that epic thread; I was hoping somebody had puzzled this out.  Guess it's my turn to puzzle something out and post a clear answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows - EPIC 0.6.44 and Eclipse 4.2. (the only issue is that you have to close and reopen Eclipse for any settings-change to take effect).

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem for me, too: Windows 7, 64-bit; Indigo; EPIC 0.6.44, ActivePerl 5.14.2.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to EPIC 0.6.55 on the [testing branch](http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates/testing) to get Perl::Critic working.

I was using EPIC on Galileo where PerlCritic was working. After installing Kepler Perl::Critic didn't work anymore. After hours I discovered that I had been on the testing branch before, where Perl::Critic works, but the new installation of Kepler put me back to "stable" EPIC 0.5.46 which seems to haven't been updated for a long time.

My config is:

- Windows ActivePerl 5.14.2
- Perl::Critic 1.121 installed with ppm under "c:\perl\site\bin"
- In EPIC preferences, the Perl::Critic location is set to "c:\perl\site\bin\perlcritic"